# How to add tags to a nuget package?

Tags: c#, github, deployment, nuget, github-actions

I am currently deploying a package to Nuget using github actions (specifically using the brandedoutcast/publish-nuget@v2.5.5 action). The package was pushed successfully but how do I add project tags and social media links like so to the project on Nuget:

[image: Tags example]

I'm using JetBrains Rider to develop the project in question, so I'm a little confused on how to edit package detains.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It doesn't matter what tooling you use, Visual Studio or Rider, they're just editing xml files (csproj or nuspec, but I'm 90% sure you'd know if you're using a nuspec file, so I bet you're using csproj for creating your package) that you can edit with a text editor. In fact, it's possible the tooling doesn't expose the full set of properties that NuGet uses from MSBuild, in which case you have no choice but to hand edit the xml yourself. This is especially true when you do "advanced" things like use a `Directory.Build.props` file to re-use the same property values across multiple projects in your repo, rather than duplicate in every project file.

Anyway, [NuGet's docs on packing with msbuild](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#pack-target) says:

> PackageTags
>
> A semicolon-delimited list of tags that designates the package.

So, in your csproj, inside a `<PropertyGroup>`, have `<PackageTags>console;shell;terminal;progress;progressbar</PackageTags>`.

For completeness, if you're using a nuspec, [the docs say the element name is just `<tags>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuspec#tags).